# TSQL: Need help splitting data sequenctially based on a delimiter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split, row, delimiter

Need assistance in splitting a row to multiple rows but in the below way:-

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mw0Ow.png)

I have found quite a number of functions which are close but not really the way i want it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For your example this is simplest solution. But I don't think that it's universal answer.

```
select ID, left(col1,1), left(col2,1), left(col3,1) from input_table
union all 
select ID, right(col1,1), right(col2,1), right(col3,1) from input_table
order by ID
```